# Score Counting Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing code for a rock paper scissors game, it has a random number generator between 1-3 which simulates the computer's throw, and it works totally fine. What I'm trying to do is add a score counting system, for 3 different scores:

- userWins
- compWins
- gamesPlayed

I also have a loop which allows you to play mulitple games.

but I can't find a way for the scores to update while playing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: i thought it was python 3, please explain the difference

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I edited your apparently incorrect tags.

Comment: Make it a class and have the scores a variables of that class and increment them for each game played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a global variable:

```
gamesPlayed = 0   
userWins = 0
compWins = 0    

def playOneRound():
  global gamesPlayed
  global userWins
  global compWins
  compThrow = getCompThrow()
  userThrow = getUserThrow()
  result = compareThrows(userThrow, compThrow)
  if result == "Win":
    print("Winner Winner Chicken Dinner")
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    userWins += 1
  elif result == "Lose":
    print("Loser Loser Chicken Loser ")
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    compWins += 1
  else:
    print("Tie")
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
  gamesPlayed += 1
```

Second, maybe better approach:

```
class Scores:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gamesPlayed = 0
        self.userWins = 0
        self.compWins = 0

scores = Scores()

def playOneRound():
  compThrow = getCompThrow()
  userThrow = getUserThrow()
  result = compareThrows(userThrow, compThrow)
  if result == "Win":
    print("Winner Winner Chicken Dinner")
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    scores.userWins += 1
  elif result == "Lose":
    print("Loser Loser Chicken Loser ")
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    scores.compWins += 1
  else:
    print("Tie")
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
  scores.gamesPlayed += 1
```

Comment: Global variables should generally be avoided. The required code changes will be somewhat more pervasive, but this strikes me as a lazy cop-out.

Comment: Well I think the best way would be to put this code into a class, but the way with the global variable is the fast and dirty way I assume ;)